# In MVC 5, returning a View with a specified name is returning the entire page within a <pre> tag

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5, html-rendering

Bear with me please, its been years since I have use MVC so I am quite rusty. But I swear this used to work. I have a view using a layout page. The layout page has a couple forms within it, in case that matters.

The Body view contains a grid and some ancillary data. On the click event of the grid, I use JavaScript to submit the form that is within the body.

Tracing through the controller code, everything looks good, the model looks good within the code, but it renders in the client within a pre tag.

I can't for the life of me figure out what I am doing wrong, and my searches are not coming up with anything relevant. Any help would be greatly appreciated! I'm slowly wearing a divot in my desk from banging my head against it.

I have trimmed out a lot of formatting garbage. Hopefully its not relevant; I have the suspicion I am doing something fundamentally wrong or out of date.

Looking at Page Source, it shows regular page source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Facilities</title>
</head>
<body>
    ...
</body>
</html>
```

Bringing up developer tools, it shows the pre tags:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">
            "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset="utf-8" /><meta name="viewport" "
            ...
        </pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

﻿
Controller:

```
public ActionResult Facilities(int selectedFacility = 0, string selectedFacilityName = "")
{
    // builds model, sets values
    return View("Facilities", model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SelectFacility(int selectedFacility)
{
    // Gets selected facility name

    // Originally tried creating a new view model, updating the 
    //    two values and displaying like this:
    // return View("~/views/account/Facilities.cshtml", model);

    // Currently trying this:
    return Facilities(selectedFacility, facilityName);
}
```

ViewModel (I don't think its too relevant though):

```
public class FacilitiesViewModel
    {
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public int SelectedFacility { get; set; }
        public string SelectedFacilityName { get; set; }
        public List<Facility> FacilityList { get; set; }
        public int? DefaultFacility { get; set; }
        public string DefaultFacilityName { get; set; }
    }
```

View:

```
@model FacilitiesViewModel
@using NonFactors.Mvc.Grid
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Facilities";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutWithMenu.cshtml";
}

<div>
    <div>
        Facilities
    </div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("SelectFacility", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { name = "frmFacilities", id = "frmFacilities" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div class="table-responsive" id="tblFacilities">
            @(Html
                .Grid(Model.FacilityList)
                .Build(columns =>
                {
                    columns.Add(model => model.FacilityId).Css("d-none");
                    columns.Add(model => model.FacilityName).Titled("Name").Css("text-start");
                    columns.Add(model => model.City).Titled("City").Css("text-start");
                    columns.Add(model => model.State).Titled("State").Css("text-start");
                })
                .Empty("No data found")
                .Filterable()
                .Sortable()
                .Pageable())
        </div>
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SelectedFacility, new { @id = "SelectedFacility" }) 
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.DefaultFacility)
    }
</div>

<script>
    function gridSelect(e) {
        if (e.detail.data["client-id"] == null) return;
        
        $("#SelectedFacility).val(e.detail.data["client-id"]);
        $("#frmFacilities").submit();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I'm encountering the same issue, and there's no JavaScript involved in the execution path that causes it. It's also kind of inconsistent because it can sometimes not happen, but once it does it seems to happen every time that particular controller is hit.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Javascript to do the post and it is returning the content to put into a placeholder on the page, then rather than returning View(), you need to return PartialView() instead.

View always returns your _layout.cshtml with the view mixed in, hence you get the full html body again.  PartialView sends back just the view without the _layout.cshtml